# How to add a new icons font like FontAwesome?

Tags: icons, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, font-awesome, sencha-architect

I've been using Sencha Touch for a long time and now I'm trying Sencha Architect. I need to include FontAwesome to use more icons in my buttons. The problem is that I don't know where I have to write:

```
@include icon-font('Awesome', inline-font-files('awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff', woff, 'awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf', truetype,'awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg', svg));
```

Besides, I'm not sure which is the folder where the fonts has to be located. If I put the fonts in resources/scss/stylesheets/fonts/awesome, the compiler throws some errors. If I put the fonts in Library/Application Support/Sencha/Sencha Architect 3.0/extracted/touch23-compile/themes/fonts, it works, but I don't think this is the best solution.

Does anybody know the best way to include new fonts to a Sencha Architect project?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can see this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606558/sencha-architect-3-does-not-use-app-css

Answer (score 3):

In 'resources->saas->stylesheets->fonts->fontAwesome' put all the .eot, .svg, .ttf and .woff files.
In your app.scss file include it

```
// Custom font
@include icon-font('CustomIcons', inline-font-files(
'fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff', woff,
'fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf', truetype,
'fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg', svg,
'fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot', eot
));
```

after

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
```

and include icons likes `@include icon("settings", '\f085', "CustomIcons");` 
Now 'settings' class can be used in iconCls to show the http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/cogs/ icon.
N.B. Don't forget to compile the scss file.

Comment: It works in Sencha Touch 2, but not in Sencha Architect 3. If I follow your instructions, it doesn't work. I think Sencha Architect doesn't use app.scss.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created this new app that will help you to prepare an icons and corresponding SASS file (`_icons-myfont.scss`) for your Sencha apps. This has been tested with Sencha Architect projects.

The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and using the tool to convert Ico Moon project files into SCSS for use in Sencha Touch.

- https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I try it,but failed.I found a easy way to make it.
1. download the font file and css,and put them into floder (like your_architect_floder/css/)
2. import the css in the architect as resources
3. add a button ,dont use "text",but use the html.
   'edit'
   amazing ?
:-D